# RDD not serializable Cassandra/Spark connector java API

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, connector, datastax

so I previously had some questions on how to query cassandra using spark in a java maven project here: [Querying Data in Cassandra via Spark in a Java Maven Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893945/querying-data-in-cassandra-via-spark-in-a-java-maven-project)

Well my question was answered and it worked, however I've run into an issue (possibly an issue). I'm trying to now use the datastax java API. Here is my code:

```
package com.angel.testspark.test2;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

import java.io.Serializable;

import static com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraJavaUtil.*;


public class App 
{

    // firstly, we define a bean class
    public static class Person implements Serializable {
        private Integer id;
        private String fname;
        private String lname;
        private String role;

        // Remember to declare no-args constructor
        public Person() { }

        public Integer getId() { return id; }
        public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }

        public String getfname() { return fname; }
        public void setfname(String fname) { this.fname = fname; }

        public String getlname() { return lname; }
        public void setlname(String lname) { this.lname = lname; }

        public String getrole() { return role; }
        public void setrole(String role) { this.role = role; }

        // other methods, constructors, etc.
    }

    private transient SparkConf conf;
    private App(SparkConf conf) {
        this.conf = conf;
    }


    private void run() {
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        createSchema(sc);


        sc.stop();
    }

    private void createSchema(JavaSparkContext sc) {

        JavaRDD<String> rdd = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("tester", "empbyrole", Person.class)
                .where("role=?", "IT Engineer").map(new Function<Person, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(Person person) throws Exception {
                        return person.toString();
                    }
                });
        System.out.println("Data as Person beans: \n" + StringUtils.join("\n", rdd.toArray()));
               }



    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Syntax: com.datastax.spark.demo.JavaDemo <Spark Master URL> <Cassandra contact point>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setAppName("Java API demo");
        conf.setMaster(args[0]);
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", args[1]);

        App app = new App(conf);
        app.run();
    }
}
```

here is my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.angel.testspark.test2.App
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1020)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1018)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1018)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:724)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.processEvent(DAGScheduler.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$start$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:190)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Now I KNOW exactly where my error is. It is `System.out.println("Data as Person beans: \n" + StringUtils.join("\n", rdd.toArray()));` because I need to convert rdd to an Array. However, the API documentation SAID i should be able to do this... this is code copied and pasted from the documentation. Why can I not serialize the RDD to an array?

I've already inserted dummy data into my cassandra using the insertions in my post that I included in the link above.

Also, a previous error that I solved was when i changed all of my getters and setters to lowercase. When I used capitals in them, it produced an error. Why can't I use capitals in my getters and setters here?

Thanks,
Angel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing `public class App` to `public class App implements Serializable` should fix the error. Because a java inner class will keep a reference to the outer class, your `Function` object will have a reference to `App`. As Spark needs to serialize your `Function` object, it requires `App` is also serializable.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Do you have any insight as to why this statement doesn't work though? `JavaRDD<String> rdd = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("tester", "empbyrole", Person.class).where("role=?", "IT Engineer").map(new Function<Person, String>()` it gives me an error if i leave the .where(), but if i remove it and leave the .map, the whole code works. it's documented that the .where should work

Comment: I posted another question on it but it has been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001566/spark-datastax-java-api-select-statements/26020947#26020947. Thank you!