# Spark Cassandra connector filtering with IN clause

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, cql, spark-cassandra-connector

I am facing some issues with spark cassandra connector filtering for java. Cassandra allows the filtering by last column of the partition key with IN clause. 
e.g

```
create table cf_text
(a varchar,b varchar,c varchar, primary key((a,b),c))

Query : select * from cf_text where a ='asdf' and b in ('af','sd');

sc.cassandraTable("test", "cf_text").where("a = ?", "af").toArray.foreach(println)
```

How count I specify the IN clause which is used in the CQL query in spark? How range queries can be specified as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just wondering, but does your Spark code above work?  I thought that Spark won't allow a `WHERE` on partition keys (`a` and `b` in your case), since it uses them under the hood (see last answer to this question): [Spark Datastax Java API Select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001566/spark-datastax-java-api-select-statements/)

In any case, with the Cassandra Spark connector, you are allowed to stack your `WHERE` clauses, and an `IN` can be specified with a `List<String>`.

```
List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<String>();
valuesList.Add("value2");
valuesList.Add("value3");

sc.cassandraTable("test", "cf")
    .where("column1 = ?", "value1")
    .where("column2 IN ?", valuesList)
    .keyBy(new Function<MyCFClass, String>() {
                public String call(MyCFClass _myCF) throws Exception {
                    return _myCF.getId();
                }
            });
```

Note that the [normal rules of using IN with Cassandra/CQL](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__selectIN) still apply here.

Range queries function in a similar manner:

```
sc.cassandraTable("test", "person")
    .where("age > ?", "15")
    .where("age < ?", "20")
    .keyBy(new Function<Person, String>() {
                public String call(Person _person) throws Exception {
                    return _person.getPersonid();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Yeah spark works on the partition key in where clause. I missed b column of the partition key(a,b) om above spark code. Both a and b should be present in the where clause.                                         sc.cassandraTable("test", "cf_text").where("a = ?", "af").where("b=?","df").toArray.foreach(println)